# Hyperledger Fabric - external chaincode with TLS from fabric-ca

Tags: ssl, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I'm trying to setup Hyperledger Fabric using the new external chaincode service feature. Running the chaincode with the default configuration (no tls or peer authentication) works as expected.

I've read quite a few tutorials about this topic, but they all only use self-signed certificates for this purpose - which is not very helpful since I am working on configuring a production system. I Would like to use the certificate authorities (fabric-ca-server) that are already running in my network and provide the certificates for my orderers, peers etc.

My question would be: How do I generate the root_cert as well as client_cert and client_key using my existing CA? There must be a way to do this using the fabric-ca-client. I've already tried to use the ca-certificate of my peer-organization, but that did not work (It does not seem to contain the hostname of the chaincode-service).

Thank you for your help.

**UPDATE**:

I've now tried to use the fabric-ca-client's register and enroll commands to register an identity and get myself an tls Enrollment-profile.

```
fabric-ca-client register --caname $CANAME --id.name chaincode --id.secret chainpw --tls.certfiles $certfile --loglevel error
fabric-ca-client enroll -u https://chaincode: chainpw@$CA_HOST_ADDRESS:$nodePort --caname $CANAME -M "$chainDir/msp" --csr.cn diplom-$validK8SHostName  --csr.hosts diplom-$validK8SHostName --tls.certfiles $certfile --loglevel error
fabric-ca-client enroll -u https://chaincode: chainpw@$CA_HOST_ADDRESS:$nodePort --caname $CANAME -M "$chainDir/tls" --enrollment.profile tls --csr.hosts diplom-$validK8SHostName --csr.hosts localhost --tls.certfiles $certfile --loglevel error
```

From the generated tls directory, I took the `/signcerts/cert.pem` and formatted it into single-line via `awk 'NF {sub(/\r/, ""); printf "%s\\n",$0;}' ...` and pasted it into the connection.json as `root_cert`.

Similarly I've copied the cert.pem file into the chaincode container and set the environment variable `CORE_CHAINCODE_TLS_CLIENT_CACERT_FILE` to point to this file. However, the peer still cannot connect to the container.

```
ClientHandshake -> ERRO 06c Client TLS handshake failed after 752.754µs with error: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake
```

**Update 2**:

Seems like I've set the wrong environment-variable on the chaincode service. `CORE_CHAINCODE_TLS_CERT_FILE` must be set to the generated `/signcerts/cert.pem` and `CORE_CHAINCODE_TLS_KEY_FILE` to private-key from `/keystore`.

The chaincode service seems to accept the certificates now, but the peer complains that they were signed by an unknown authority.

**Update 3**:

Another bit of progress. Seems like I made a mistake in the `fabric-ca-client` commands. I accidentally set the csr.cn parameter, thereby overwriting my CA hostname. With he following I was able to register my chaincode service with my CA and get the corresponding TLS certificates to be valid for my service and checkout with the organisations CA :-)

```
fabric-ca-client register --caname $CANAME --id.name $NAME --id.secret $PW --tls.certfiles $certfile --loglevel error
fabric-ca-client enroll -u https://$NAME:$PW@$CA_HOST_ADDRESS:$nodePort --caname $CANAME -M "$chainDir/msp" --csr.hosts chain-$validK8SHostName --tls.certfiles $certfile --loglevel error
fabric-ca-client enroll -u https://$NAME:$PW@$CA_HOST_ADDRESS:$nodePort --caname $CANAME -M "$chainDir/tls" --enrollment.profile tls --csr.hosts chain-$validK8SHostName --csr.hosts localhost --tls.certfiles $certfile --loglevel error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I was able to find an answer to my problem. As stated in my third update, I've used the `fabric-ca-client` to enrol an identity for my chaincode-service.

```
fabric-ca-client register --caname $CANAME --id.name $NAME --id.secret $PW --tls.certfiles $certfile --loglevel error
fabric-ca-client enroll -u https://$NAME:$PW@$CA_HOST_ADDRESS:$nodePort --caname $CANAME -M "$chainDir/msp" --csr.hosts chain-$validK8SHostName --tls.certfiles $certfile --loglevel error
fabric-ca-client enroll -u https://$NAME:$PW@$CA_HOST_ADDRESS:$nodePort --caname $CANAME -M "$chainDir/tls" --enrollment.profile tls --csr.hosts chain-$validK8SHostName --csr.hosts localhost --tls.certfiles $certfile --loglevel error
```

Pleas note that the `validK8SHostName` is simply the hostname of my container with the dots replaced by dashes (k8s does not allow dots in service or container names).

These commands generate an `msp` and `tls` folder in my `chaindDir`. The certificates/keys referenced as JSON-propeties are converted into single-line using `awk 'NF {sub(/\r/, ""); printf "%s\\n",$0;}'`. The environment variables of the chaincode container are the actual files (I've mounted them as secrets in my k8s cluster).

- `tls/signcerts` -> Certificated needed for the "root_cert" property and the CORE_CHAINCODE_TLS_CERT_FILE env.
- `tls/keystore` -> Private key that is set for the CORE_CHAINCODE_TLS_KEY_FILE env.
- `tls/tlscacerts` -> Certificate needed for the CORE_CHAINCODE_TLS_CLIENT_CA_CERT_FILE env.
- `msp/signcert` -> Certificate needed for the "client_cert" property.
- `msp/keystore` -> Private key that is set for the "client_key" property

With the setup I can start chaincode containers that are TLS-terminated and only communicate with those peers, that have the corresponding Certificate and private-key combination. Thereby all certificates and keys are generated by my organisations CA.

Answer (score 1):

For additional information, https://github.com/hyperledgendary/contract-as-a-service is an example repo that shows the chaincode as an external service.

The approach taken there is indeed what Victor has describe above, and is, AFAIK a good way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The Fabric CA docs on [initializing a CA server](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/users-guide.html#initializing-the-server) mentions:

> The `fabric-ca-server init` command generates a self-signed CA
> certificate unless the `-u <parent-fabric-ca-server-URL>` option is
> specified. If the `-u` is specified, the server’s CA certificate is
> signed by the parent Fabric CA server. In order to authenticate to the
> parent Fabric CA server, the URL must be of the form
> `<scheme>://<enrollmentID>:<secret>@<host>:<port>`, where `<enrollmentID>`
> and `<secret>` correspond to an identity with an `hf.IntermediateCA`
> attribute whose value equals `true`.

It also says you can set a key and certificate file which has already been generated

> If you want the Fabric CA server to use a CA signing certificate and
> key file which you provide, you must place your files in the location
> referenced by `ca.certfile` and `ca.keyfile` respectively. Both files must
> be PEM-encoded and must not be encrypted. More specifically, the
> contents of the CA certificate file must begin with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` and the contents of the key file must begin with
> `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` and not `-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----`.

So if you already a CA server running, it should be possible to get a certificate signed by it or to create one and include it in your child CA

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, this is not what I am trying to achieve. The CA-Servers are up and running (one for each organisation as well as the one for the orderers). I am not trying to configure a ca-server as intermediate ca.
What I am trying to do is to get a TLS-certificate as well as key-pairs that I can use for the external chaincode service from the existing organisation CA :-)

Answer (score 0):

I renamed the files to sync with [readme](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/main/asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-external/README.md) and followed  to make it working by updating the `connection.json` and `docker-compose-cc.yaml` file

```
  cp ${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/myorg1/chaincode/msp/signcerts/* ${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/myorg1/chaincode/msp/client.crt
  cp ${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/myorg1/chaincode/msp/keystore/* ${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/myorg1/chaincode/msp/client.key

  cp ${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/myorg1/chaincode/tls/keystore/* ${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/myorg1/chaincode/tls/server.key
  cp ${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/myorg1/chaincode/tls/signcerts/* ${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/myorg1/chaincode/tls/server.crt
  cp ${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/myorg1/chaincode/tls/tlscacerts/* ${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/myorg1/chaincode/tls/root_ca.crt
```